# Javascript download stop in firefox, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a simple button in my HTML page, for downloading a SVG file. This works in Chrome perfectly fine, but in Firefox the file hast just 1 line (the first).

```
$("button").click(function(){
    svgSource = phylocanvas.getSvgSource();
    console.log(svgSource);
    if(svgSource){
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement); // Add the element to the DOM
        hiddenElement.setAttribute("type", "hidden"); // make it hidden
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(svgSource);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = '<TMPL_VAR NAME="TREENAME">.svg';
        console.log(hiddenElement.download);
        hiddenElement.click();
    }
});
```

Any idea how to get the whole file in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try:

```
var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,' + window.encodeURIComponent(textContent));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);

pom.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Replace textContent and filename.

Answer (score 0):

An http request can contain a header variable `ContentDisposition` that is a equivalent for the download attribute. As far as I know, the only difference between Firefox and Chrome is that, with Firefox the header attribute has priority and with Chrome the download attribute wins. Perhaps in Chrome the download attribute is used and the file is downloaded as it is, while in Firefox the header attribute (if provided) is used and has a ??? value that only saves the xml header of the file while the content is send the the svg renderer. (Just a guess ;-) )